# How to ignore trailing whitespace errors with git stash

Tags: git, git-stash

I have an unusual problem with git. I've pulled from a repo I haven't used in awhile, and for simplicity let's say I have two branches, develop and master. I was already in develop, and checked out master. I made no changes, I was just looking at the files. When I went to checkout develop, I could not because README.md was modified. Git diff showed the whole file was changed, with identical content, so I thought that was some sort of whitespace error.

I did git checkout -- README.md, and it still appeared modified. So then I tried git stash -p (so I could just stash that file). That gave me:

```
warning: 3 lines add whitespace errors.
```

It went on to say:

```
warning: squelched 55 whitespace errors
warning: 60 lines add whitespace errors.
```

And the file is still modified.

Is there any way to get around these errors? What could be causing it?

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned above, the issue is named **trailing whitespace**.
Git has several ways to handle whitespace. You can read about it here:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_formatting_and_whitespace

You can try and set the configuration values:

```
$ git config --global core.whitespace \
                      trailing-space, \
                      -space-before-tab, \
                      indent-with-non-tab, \
                      tab-in-indent, \
                      cr-at-eol
```

When git pops up content from a stash, it's adding it back to the working directory using the `apply` command, so you can disable the `apply` warning with this configuration

```
git config --global apply.whitespace nowarn
or 
git config --global core.whitespace fix
```

> #`core.whitespace`
> A comma separated list of common whitespace problems to notice.
> `git diff` will use `color.diff.whitespace` to highlight them,
> and `git apply --whitespace=error` will consider them as errors.

> You can prefix `-` to disable any of them (e.g. `-trailing-space`):

> ###`blank-at-eol`
> treats trailing whitespaces at the end of the line as an error (enabled by default).

> ###`space-before-tab`
> treats a space character that appears immediately before a tab character in the initial indent part of the line as an error (enabled by default).

> ###`indent-with-non-tab`
> treats a line that is indented with space characters instead of the equivalent tabs as an error (not enabled by default).

> ###`tab-in-indent`
> treats a tab character in the initial indent part of the line as an error (not enabled by default).

> ###`blank-at-eof`
> treats blank lines added at the end of file as an error (enabled by default).

> ###`trailing-space`
> is a short-hand to cover both blank-at-eol and blank-at-eof.

> ###`cr-at-eol`
> treats a carriage-return at the end of line as part of the line terminator, i.e. with it, trailing-space does not trigger if the character before such a carriage-return is not a whitespace (not enabled by default).

> ###`tabwidth=<n>`
> tells how many character positions a tab occupies; this is relevant for indent-with-non-tab and when Git fixes tab-in-indent errors. The default tab width is 8. Allowed values are 1 to 63.

Comment: I had no luck at all with changing the whitespace configuration values, and even "git reset --hard HEAD" did not work. The only thing that worked was "git checkout -f develop".